# Ordenar elementos jTextField en Java Swing

Tags: java, jtextfield

Tengo un `JFrame` con elementos `jTextField`, todos ellos en un mismo `jPanel`.

**¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se me seleccione el primer campo que esté vacío al enviar un formulario incompleto?** Otorgando yo el orden que quiero que tengan los `jTextField`.

He intentado utilizar la Clase **FocusTraversalPolicy**:

**Clase FocusTraversalPolicy:**

```
package bbdd;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.util.Vector;

public abstract class MyFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy {
    Vector<Component> order;

    public MyFocusTraversalPolicy(Vector<Component> order) {
        this.order = new Vector<Component>(order.size());
        this.order.addAll(order);
    }
}
```

**Clase Nuevo_cliente:**

```
package interfaz;

import bbdd.Conexiones;
import bbdd.Cliente;
import bbdd.MyFocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
    public class Nuevo_cliente extends javax.swing.JDialog implements FocusListener{
        /**
         * Constructor de la clase Nuevo_cliente.
         * @param parent
         * @param modal 
         */
        public Nuevo_cliente(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
            super(parent, modal);
            initComponents();
            ...
            ...
            ...
            //Otorgar orden personal a los jTextField cuando estén los campos vacíos.
            Vector<Component> order = new Vector<Component>(4);
            order.add(textfield_nombre);
            order.add(textfield_apellidos);
            order.add(textfield_DNI);
            order.add(textfield_telefono);
            order.add(textfield_direccion);
            order.add(textfield_ciudad);
            order.add(textfield_email);
            MyFocusTraversalPolicy newPolicy = new MyFocusTraversalPolicy(order);
            this.setFocusTraversalPolicy(newPolicy);
        }

        /**
         * Validar formulario y comprobar campos vacíos de tipo JTextField.
         * @return 
         */
        private boolean validateForm() {
            for(int i=0; i<Panel_Cliente.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                JComponent c = (JComponent)Panel_Cliente.getComponent(i);
                if(c instanceof JTextField) {
                    if(((JTextField)c).getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                        ((JTextField)c).requestFocus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Método - Dar de alta un nuevo cliente en la base de datos.
         * @param evt 
         */
        private void button_OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
            String nombre = textfield_nombre.getText();
            String apellidos = textfield_apellidos.getText();
            String DNI = textfield_DNI.getText();
            String telefono = textfield_telefono.getText();
            String direccion = textfield_direccion.getText();
            String ciudad = textfield_ciudad.getText();
            String email = textfield_email.getText();

            //Comprobamos que están todos los datos insertados...
            if (!textfield_nombre.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !textfield_apellidos.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                    && !textfield_DNI.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !textfield_telefono.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                    && !textfield_direccion.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !textfield_ciudad.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                    && !textfield_email.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                ) {
                if(!isDNI(textfield_DNI.getText())){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Formato de DNI incorrecto!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    textfield_DNI.requestFocus();
                }else if(!isEmail(textfield_email.getText())){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Formato de email incorrecto!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    textfield_email.requestFocus();
                }else if(!Conexiones.cargar_dni().contains(textfield_DNI.getText())) {
                    Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nombre, apellidos, DNI, telefono, direccion, ciudad, email);
                    Conexiones.alta_cliente(cliente);
                    dispose();
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Este DNI ya EXISTE en la base de datos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    textfield_DNI.requestFocus();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡¡Debes rellenar TODOS los campos!!!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                textfield_nombre.requestFocus();
            }
        }                                         
    }
```

**Al intentar compilar me da fallo en la línea:**

```
MyFocusTraversalPolicy newPolicy = new MyFocusTraversalPolicy(order);
```

**Error:**

```
Implement all abstract methods
```

¿Cómo vinculo ese orden creado con la clase `FocusTraversalPolicy` a cuando, al pulsar el `button_OK`, se quede algún campo vacío y ponga el foco del ratón en el primer campo vacío?